VS Code navigate to top of file explorer tree
Excuse me if this has been answered elsewhere but I cannot seem to find a quick and simple solution to what I think is a pretty basic question!
So, what keyboard shortcut must I use to jump to the top of the File Explorer tree in VS Code?
If I've got a lot of folders open I can collapse them all with the little icon at the top but it still leaves me sitting wherever I was in the tree, meaning I have to scroll all the way to the top, or carefully drag the scroll bar up all the way. Very carefully, because if I miss and click on a file it opens it in the editor window! I just want to zoom right to the top in one easy movement!

The command you want is list.focusFirst. You can edit keybindings.
More broadly, for navigation questions, see How can I navigate and manipulate list views in VS Code using the keyboard?.

I considered duplicate closure, but am not sure if it would be allowed (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/11107541)

That does it nicely! I have to use Fn+Home because Home is on the Left Arrow button as a function option on my Dell laptop but apart from that, you were right.  Thanks!
